# Is it possible to share iCloud Notes read-only?

Tags: icloud, notes.app

I've just written up instructions for my Mum on how to use the AppleTV but I'm scared she's going to accidentally delete the contents of the note. Is it not possible to share a note "read only"?

There's a label saying "People you invite can make changes" but there seems to be no way to edit the permissions before inviting.

Maybe this is coming in iOS 11?

Comment: Not sure if this works, but have you tried locking the note after sharing it?

Comment: @not2savvy Great idea! However, I just tried it and get `Shared notes can't be locked.`

Comment: Is there *any* iOS app that can do this? I need this as well.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I would recommend Pages for doing this. (Not having Pages installed, I tested on Numbers.)

[image: Pages / Numbers read-only sharing]

Answer (score 3):

I know this isn't really how you're wanting to solve this, but you could simply compose a note with the desired content, and then either screen cap it or print to pdf and insert the screen cap or pdf back into a shared note, presuming you wanted to keep this content within the notes app.

Answer (score 2):

Answering as Notes app is updating in macOS Catalina(version 10.15) and Yes, you can share notes with "Read-Only mode" now

[image]

Comment: Welcome to Ask Different!  The original question is 3 years old so it would be helpful for you to include the OS version in your answer.  Just saying "Notes is updated" doesn't help people to know which Notes version you're referencing.  See [answer] for helpful info.

Comment: Thanks for your response. I will take care from next time onwards:)